# How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, sh

I want to execute `mongo` commands in shell script, e.g. in a script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo myDbName
db.mycollection.findOne()
show collections
```

When I execute this script via `./test.sh`, then the connection to MongoDB is established, but the following commands are not executed.

**How to execute other commands through shell script `test.sh`?**

Comment: mongo shell is deprecated now and replaced by mogosh and indeed has been removed in v6

Answer (score 574, accepted):

You can also evaluate a command using the `--eval` flag, if it is just a single command.

```
mongo --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())"
```

**Please note:** if you are using Mongo operators, starting with a $ sign, you'll want to surround the eval argument in single quotes to keep the shell from evaluating the operator as an environment variable:

```
mongo --eval 'db.mycollection.update({"name":"foo"},{$set:{"this":"that"}});' myDbName
```

Otherwise you may see something like this:

```
mongo --eval "db.test.update({\"name\":\"foo\"},{$set:{\"this\":\"that\"}});"
> E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: For `.find()` operations, you need to call an operation on the result object to print the documents, such as `toArray()` or `shellPrint()`. e.g., `mongo userdb --eval "printjson(db.users.find().toArray())"`

Comment: I had to specify the connection string like mongo <ip>:<port>/db --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())" or mongo <ip>:<port>/db < mongoCommands.js to prevent it from always connecting to "test"

Comment: Thanks @Gingi - my preferred method is `mongo mydb --eval "db.users.find({a:'b'}).pretty().shellPrint()"` ... simples :)

Comment: i wish i would get ALL of the results, instead of seeing it primt out "type 'it' for more"

Comment: While this works, the problem is that not only the result of the query is sent but also noise like connection status messages:

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: myhost
DBQuery: mydb.mycollection -> { }
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: myhost

`query result`

more noise

Comment: How do I define my servername and dbname?

Comment: @Amida you can do `mongo --eval "db.version()" --quiet` for example to avoid printing all the noise you say

Comment: if you want valid JSON output, use JSON.stringify() instead of printjson()

Comment: `mongo --eval "db.test.update({\"name\":\"foo\"},{$set:{\"this\":\"that\"}});"
> E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` If you see this error, please do not try to solve this with surround the text $set in single quotes or double quotes, that cause your data lost because script will understand `$set` as new property and without $set, your document is overridden by new document with some fields like this `"": this: "that"`.

Comment: double quote version works if you escape any $ operators like this: `mongo --eval "db.${Collection}.updateMany({},{ \$set: {${Field}:${Value}}});"` Allows to include shell tokens inline as well

Comment: @colintobing `mongo dbname --eval 'db.test.findOne()'`

Comment: will this exit mongo shell gracefully ?

Answer (score 377):

Put your mongo script into a `.js` file.

Then execute `mongo < yourFile.js`

Ex:

demo.js  //file has your script

```
use sample  //db name
show collections
```

keep this file in "c:\db-scripts"

Then in cmd prompt go to "c:\db-scripts"

```
C:\db-scripts>mongo < demo.js
```

This will execute the code in mongo and shows the output

```
C:\db-scripts>mongo < demo.js
Mongo shell version: 3.0.4
Connecting to: test
switched to db sample
users   //collection name
tasks   //collection name
bye
C:\db-scripts>
```

Comment: Quite literally.. you take the exact same commands you would input to the mongo shell, save those commands to a `.js` file, and pass it as a parameter to the `mongo` command.

Comment: It's worth noting anything you set in an --eval statement (if supplied) to the mongo interpreter will remain in scope when your script (if supplied) is executed. You can use this make your scripts more reusable, eg.

mongo --eval "somevar='someval';" db_name script_that_uses_somevar.js

Comment: @Matt -- Note that the non-JavaScript commands that the shell provides are not available in an executed JavaScript file, so `use dbName` and `show dbs` will work from the shell's internal prompt but not from inside a `.js` file.  There are JavaScript equivalents for the non-JavaScript commands, so this isn't a limitation, just something you need to be aware of.

Comment: If you need to specify a name of a database, user name, password, you can do `mongo dbName -u userName -p "password with spaces" scriptToRun.js`

Comment: This doesn't work if you want a dynamic behavior, i.e. pass arguments: `mongo < demo.js arg1 arg2 arg3` - how would you read them in the `js` file?

Comment: is there a way to keep the mongo prompt open? AKA I don't want mongo to say "bye" to me.

Comment: use `mongo --quiet ` for not print bye and version.

Comment: i had a bunch of remove commands one per line db.c3.remove({"name" : "Suriname"})
db.c3.remove({"name" : "Greenland"}) worked after i put a semi colon at end of every line. on ubuntu with \n as new line char (i created the file from Java code)

Comment: Is it required to use Javascript? I'm making a mongo script to delete and then reload data into a collection. But my we don't use .js much, we use Golang, and some bash scripts.

Comment: @ineedtoknow yes. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-file - you could still write a Go program to do this, it's just not related to mongo CLI

Comment: How do you do this in powershell? I get a `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.` error

Comment: `& cmd.exe /c "mongo < demo.js"` is the answer

Comment: I prefer entering the mongo prompt open as @AlexanderMills asks, by entering the mongo environment and running in there `load("filename.js")` which runs the script normally, ending with `true` and keeps the prompt open.

Comment: note that for all answers where the commands are piped into mongo using `<` or `|`, there is no error handling. if a command fails, the next row will still be executed. this could be a problem if you need kind of an atomic/transactional behaviour

Answer (score 116):

This works for me under Linux:

```
mongo < script.js
```

For newer version of mongodb

```
mongosh < script.js
```

Answer (score 71):

Put this in a file called `test.js`:

```
db.mycollection.findOne()
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
  print(collection);
});
```

then run it with `mongo myDbName test.js`.

Comment: How to pass values to script from bash? I want to insert name into db which is available in bash as variable and I want to pass it to script(js)

Comment: This is a much better solution, When I pipe in a file to mongo I get js syntax errors.

Comment: Inside the loop, other commands are not executed.

Answer (score 46):

There is an [official documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell) page about this as well.

Examples from that page include:

```
mongo server:27017/dbname --quiet my_commands.js
mongo test --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
```

Answer (score 41):

The shell script below also worked nicely for me... definite had to use the redirect that Antonin mentioned at first... that gave me the idea to test the here document.

```
function testMongoScript {
    mongo <<EOF
    use mydb
    db.leads.findOne()
    db.leads.find().count()
EOF
}
```

Comment: Great answer! For multiple commands, this also works: `echo -e "use mydb\ndb.leads.findOne()\ndb.leads.find().count()" | mongo`

Comment: Definitely useful because you cannot use "use mydb" within a JS file.

Comment: Thank you for this! Finally I am able to call `use another_db`. :-)

Comment: Actually you can switch DB from within a mongo script: `db = db.getSiblingDB('otherdb');`

Comment: Just what I needed. However if you only need to use one database, you can pass the database name to the mongo command, e.g. `mongo mydb <<EOF` etc.

Comment: works for me! Although my code editor is not liking the `<<EOF`

Answer (score 27):

In case you have authentication enabled:

```
mongo -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase auth_db_name < your_script.js
```

For newer version

```
mongosh -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase auth_db_name < your_script.js
```

Answer (score 24):

I use the "heredoc" syntax, which David Young mentions.  But there is a catch:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

mongo <db> <<EOF
db.<collection>.find({
  fieldName: { $exists: true }
})
.forEach( printjson );
EOF
```

The above will NOT work, because the phrase "$exists" will be seen by the shell and substituted with the value of the environment variable named "exists."  Which, likely, doesn't exist, so after shell expansion, it becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

mongo <db> <<EOF
db.<collection>.find({
  fieldName: { : true }
})
.forEach( printjson );
EOF
```

In order to have it pass through you have two options.  One is ugly, one is quite nice.  First, the ugly one: escape the $ signs:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

mongo <db> <<EOF
db.<collection>.find({
  fieldName: { \$exists: true }
})
.forEach( printjson );
EOF
```

I do NOT recommend this, because it is easy to forget to escape.

The other option is to escape the EOF, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

mongo <db> <<\EOF
db.<collection>.find({
  fieldName: { $exists: true }
})
.forEach( printjson );
EOF
```

Now, you can put all the dollar signs you want in your heredoc, and the dollar signs are ignored.  The down side: That doesn't work if you need to put shell parameters/variables in your mongo script.

Another option you can play with is to mess with your shebang.  For example,

```
#!/bin/env mongo
<some mongo stuff>
```

There are several problems with this solution:

1. It only works if you are trying to make a mongo shell script executable from the command line.  You can't mix regular shell commands with mongo shell commands.  And all you save by doing so is not having to type "mongo" on the command line...  (reason enough, of course)
2. It functions exactly like "mongo <some-js-file>" which means it does not let you use the "use <db>" command.

I have tried adding the database name to the shebang, which you would think would work.  Unfortunately, the way the system processes the shebang line, everything after the first space is passed as a single parameter (as if quoted) to the env command, and env fails to find and run it.

Instead, you have to embed the database change within the script itself, like so:

```
#!/bin/env mongo
db = db.getSiblingDB('<db>');
<your script>
```

As with anything in life, "there is more than one way to do it!"

Comment: If you quote your HEREDOC delimiter the shell will not interpret nor substitute anything, eg instead of 
blah blah << HEREDOC_EOF
stuff
EOF

Use
blah blah << "EOF"
stuf
EOF

Comment: this is a very good answer !! how can i pass shell variable to the query ?

Comment: The answer is to not escape your HEREDOC.  Then, you will be able to substitute within it.  Catch is, you will have to escape any literal dollar signs.

Answer (score 23):

In my setup I have to use:

```
mongo --host="the.server.ip:port" databaseName theScript.js
```

For newer version of mongodb

```
mongosh --host="the.server.ip:port" databaseName theScript.js
```

Answer (score 17):

How about this:

```
echo "db.mycollection.findOne()" | mongo myDbName
echo "show collections" | mongo myDbName
```

Comment: Or a bit more readable:

    echo "db.mycollection.findOne()" | mongo myDbName --quiet | python -m json.tool

Comment: This is useful to execute something after `.mongorc` has been loaded (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file)

Comment: can i put the result in a variable in the shell ?

Answer (score 17):

Thank you `printf`!  In a Linux environment, here's a better way to have only one file run the show.  Say you have two files, `mongoCmds.js` with multiple commands:

```
use someDb
db.someColl.find()
```

and then the driver shell file, `runMongoCmds.sh`

```
mongo < mongoCmds.js
```

Newer version of mongodb

```
mongosh < mongoCmds.js
```

Instead, have just one file, runMongoCmds.sh containing

```
printf "use someDb\ndb.someColl.find()" | mongo
```

Bash's `printf` is much more robust than `echo` and allows for the `\n` between commands to force them on multiple lines.

Answer (score 17):

Create a script file; write commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo < file.js
```

For newer versions
mongosh < file.js

In `file.js` write your mongo query:

```
db.collection.find({"myValue":null}).count();
```

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I can conveniently use `\n` as separator for the next mongo command I want to execute then pipe them to `mongo`

```
echo $'use your_db\ndb.yourCollection.find()' | mongo
```

Newer version of mongodb

```
echo $'use your_db\ndb.yourCollection.find()' | mongosh
```

Answer (score 15):

As suggested by `theTuxRacer`, you can use the *eval* command, for those who are missing it like I was, you can also add in your db name if you are not trying to preform operation on the default db.

```
mongo <dbname> --eval "printjson(db.something.find())"
```

Newer version of mongodb

```
mongosh <dbname> --eval "printjson(db.something.find())"
```

Answer (score 11):

```
mongo <<EOF
use <db_name>
db.getCollection("<collection_name>").find({})
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

--shell flag can also be used for javascript files

```
 mongo --shell /path/to/jsfile/test.js
```

Comment: I think this just leaves the shell open after js executed?  `mongo /path/to/jsfile/test.js` will exectute the js too.

Answer (score 4):

```
mongo db_name --eval "db.user_info.find().forEach(function(o) {print(o._id);})"
```

Answer (score 4):

Recently migrated from mongodb to Postgres. This is how I used the scripts.

```
mongo < scripts.js > inserts.sql
```

Read the `scripts.js` and output redirect to `inserts.sql`.

`scripts.js` looks like this

```
use myDb;
var string = "INSERT INTO table(a, b) VALUES";
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({}).forEach(function (object) {
    string += "('" + String(object.description) + "','" + object.name + "'),";
});
print(string.substring(0, string.length - 1), ";");
```

`inserts.sql` looks like this

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b) VALUES('abc', 'Alice'), ('def', 'Bob'), ('ghi', 'Claire');
```

Comment: Very interesting, but off topic with regard to the original question.

Comment: `How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?` This is not off-topic. In fact, I reached this question due to the title. So people like me benefit reading such an answer.
Also, I am giving a very useful method in the example rather than a toy example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle it with one line it's an easy way.

```
file.sh --> db.EXPECTED_COLLECTION.remove("_id":1234)

cat file.sh | mongo <EXPECTED_COLLECTION>
```

Answer (score 3):

Single shell script solution with ability to pass mongo arguments (`--quiet`, dbname, etc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S mongo --quiet localhost:27017/test

cur = db.myCollection.find({});
while(cur.hasNext()) {
  printjson(cur.next());
}
```

The `-S` flag might not work on all platforms.

Comment: It seems odd to me that this is not more widely appreciated... You could also just shebang the full path to a specific mongo, right?

Answer (score 2):

The legacy mongo shell has been removed from MongoDB with the version 6 release in 2022

There is a new way to execute shell scripts using the new shell, *mongosh*

From the [shell documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts) on writing scripts:

- You can use *mongosh* to execute a script from the command line without entering the *mongosh* console
- To specify the filename, use the --file or -f parameter to specify the filename
- You may also need to specify connection information

For example:

```
mongosh dbName --eval "db.users.find()"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a replicaset, writes must be done on the PRIMARY, so I usually use syntax like this which avoids having to figure out which host is the master:

`mongo -host myReplicaset/anyKnownReplica`

Comment: This does not answer the question “_How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?_”