# How to execute mongo commands from bash?

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

I am trying to run this command from bash script:

```
 mongo 192.168.10.20:27000 --eval "use admin && db.shutdownServer() && quit()"
```

but i get this error :

```
[rs.initiate() && use admin && db.shutdownServer() && quit()] doesn't exist
```

how can i do it without using a js file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are [differences between interactive & scripted `mongo` shell sessions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo). In particular, commands like `use admin` are not valid JavaScript and will only work in an interactive shell session.

The working equivalent of your shutdown command line would be:

```
mongo 192.168.10.20:27000/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"
```

You can include the database to use in the connection string, and there is no need to quit from a scripted `mongo` shell session.

If you do need to change databases from a scripted session, there is a [`db.getSiblingDB()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) JavaScript function. An alternative way to write the shutdown command above would be:

```
 mongo 192.168.10.20:27000 --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB('admin');db.shutdownServer()"
```

Comment: @MoienGK Yes, you can put longer JavaScript in the `--eval`. Separate multiple statements with semicolons as per my second example.

Comment: unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: shutdown must run from localhost when running db without auth"

Comment: thanks, is putting && instead of semi colon, makes second command dependent on first one's success?

Comment: The error message explains the issue: your version of MongoDB only accepts shutdown command from localhost unless you have authentication enabled. You should enable authentication on your MongoDB instance or work out a different approach for shutting down the server (i.e. run your bash command via ssh). The `&&` syntax is specific to bash commands, not JavaScript. If you want to write a more advanced script with error checking I would encourage you to save this in a JS file which can also be passed in a bash command line (`mongo foo.js`). What's your reason for not wanting to use a JS file?

Comment: actually i started with .js but it bothered me a bit , i thought too much headache for small code. but it seems that i was wrong

Comment: FYI, example of running the same command line via ssh (if you don't want to enable auth for some reason, though doing so is definitely recommended): `ssh user@192.168.10.20 'mongo localhost:27000/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"'`. Replace "user" with a valid username on the remote server.

Comment: there is one other problem. there is no mongo (client or shell) is installed on remote server.so i can not use commands that i need from remote server. so i guess sending the js file to remote server wont solve auth problem

Comment: If you don't want to install a `mongo` shell on the database server, I would recommend enabling authentication (even if this is on your local network). There's a [MongoDB security checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) which has a list of best practices.

Answer (score 13):

You can use heredoc syntax.

```
#! /bin/sh
mongo <<EOF
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
quit()
exit
```

Turns out heredoc syntax throws a warning when EOF is missing at the end for bash script. This is the bash script version.

```
#! /bin/bash
mongo <<EOF
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
quit()
EOF
```

Here is the output, I guess this is what you expected.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: test
switched to db admin
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.808 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.810 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.810 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 ok
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.812 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.812 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
Wed Jun 24 17:07:23.812 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
```

Comment: this seems correct. but i have other irrelevent issue now: shutdown must run from localhost when running db without auth.thanks for reply

Answer (score 4):

From the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/):

> **--eval option**
>
> Use the *--eval* option to mongo to pass the shell a JavaScript fragment, as in the following:
> `mongo test --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"`

You can also put your JS Fragments into a `.js` file then do:

```
mongo < myScript.js
```

You may also find more useful stuff in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts)