# How to get unix timestamp from shell into a mongodump command

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, unix

I want to create a script to backup a collection in MongoDB on a daily basis. I want it to be run at 00:30 every day to backup data that has been inserted to this collection during the day before. When I do this manually I run it like this:

```
mongodump -d History  -c history -q '{ czas:  { $gte: new Date(1443571201000), $lte: new Date(1443657540000)} }' --out /home/test/backup
```

now I want those unix timestamp to be generated automatically. In a bash this command makes the trick:

```
TZ=UTC date --date="`date +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d '1 day ago'`" +"%s"
```

But I dont know how to combine it in a mongodb command. This command fails:

```
mongodump -d History  -c history -q '{ czas:  { $gte: new Date(`date --date="`date +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d '2 days ago'`" +"%s"`), $lte: new Date(`date --date="`date +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d '1 day ago'`" +"%s"`)} }' --out /home/test/backup
```

with a message:

```
2015-11-26T16:45:03.051+0100    positional arguments not allowed: [days ago`" +"%s"`), $lte: new Date(`TZ=UTC date --date="`date +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" -d 1 day ago`" +"%s"`)} }]
```

I'm not unix guru, please help me how to get this working.

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: Related: [executing shell (bash) commands from within the mongo client](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112113/27119). In general, it is a bad idea.

Comment: Mongodump will be run from shell and not from mongo client. I want to create a bash script that will be run from crontab. I just need to know how to put that calculated unixtimestamp value inside mongodump command

Comment: Probably with [`eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6000360/1983854)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell won't be able to provide values inside of single quotes (it assumes 'literal values' vs 'get_these values') so, try something like:

```
START_DATE="some value"  
END_DATE="some value"  

"{ czas:  { $gte: new Date(${START_DATE}), $lte: new Date(${END_DATE})} }"
```

I would hope that the manual for the tool you are using would provide a solution; I am guessing that the syntax requires a 'Epoch Date' (seconds since the 'Epoch'.)

:)
Dale