# How to run mongo db script on remote server?

Tags: java, mongodb

how to run a Mongo db script on a remote server?

I know below command can be used for the same on local as mentioned here:[How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts)

```
mongo < yourFile.js
```

I want to run this script on a remote server

mongodb:uri:mongodb://user:password@mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb

Comment: Did you try connecting with the shell? What does this have to do with spring?

Comment: SSH there and do your job.

Comment: There is no direct use of spring to push this script.i will be using spring to fetch the contents later.Not tried with shell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Mongo on local machine :

```
 mongo -u <user> -p <password> mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb <yourFile.js>
```

Comment: It works..Thanks!                                                                                                        
       mongo -u user -p password 
       mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb < yourFile.js -changed for better file read from the path where 'yourFile.js' exist.

Comment: what about on remote server ?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little bit off topic, but in case you want to / have to use Powershell for a lack of options, you can run:

```
(Get-Content yourFile.js) | & mongo.exe 'mongodb://user:password@mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb'
```

or

```
"print('Hello');print('Hello')" | & mongo.exe 'mongodb://user:password@mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb'
```

or

```
& 'mongo.exe' 'mongodb://user:password@mongodb01d.mydomain.com:27017/mydb' --eval "print('Hello');print('Hello')"
```

I had some difficulties with `$regex`, because Powershell interpreted it as a variable, so I had to use `` `$regex `` (with an additional backtick) instead.

Answer (score 0):

**For standalone mongo setup (single node)**

```
mongo -u <user> -p <password> mongodb://HOST_IP:27017/DB_NAME --eval 'MONGO_QUERY'
```

**Example:**

`mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test --eval 'db.collection.count()'`

**For clustered mongo setup (Replicaset with multiple nodes)**

```
mongo -u <user> -p <password> mongodb://NODE_1_IP:27017,NODE_2_IP:27017,NODE_3_IP:27017/DB_NAME?replicaSet=RS_ID --eval 'MONGO_QUERY'
```

**Example:**

`mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.2:27017,127.0.0.3:27017/test?replicaSet=rs0 --eval 'db.collection.count()'`

PS: The user/pass in the above examples have been ignored but you need to add them if mongo has to auth.