# Issue in executing mongo commands through shell script

Tags: mongodb

Based on the answer by Matt for the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts):

I tried the below script

```
use sample

db.testCollection.insert({"result":1})
```

However when I run as suggested, get an error as below and the record gets inserted in a collection of the default db and not in the 'sample' db as expected.

```
[tmp]# mongo < output.js
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-21T14:54:52.713+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shellhelp2):1:21
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
bye
```

Kindly request for help.

Comment: try using `db.'testCollection'.insert({"result":1})`

Comment: This did not work, gave a different error

Comment: try this db.getCollection(testCollection).insert({"result":1})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the db name as shown below.

```
mongo your-db-name < output.js
```

Answer (score 8):

Your script and command are correct.
On Unix, you will get this error if your script has Dos/Windows end of lines (CRLF) instead of Unix end of lines (LF).

To convert your end of lines :

```
dos2unix output.js
```

or: [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script)