# How to make lunux shell script for using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can connect to mongodb by mongoose in nodejs as below.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/something', dbOptions, err => {
  if(err) { return process.exit(1) }

  someSchema.findOne({}, result =>{
    if(!result) { someSchema.insert({some object}) }
    return process.exit(0)
  })
})
```

I can run this file on nodejs without problem. 
But I want to run this file on lunux shell script. How can I make this concept on shell script? Could you give me some advice? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000360/1497533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts)

Comment: Another solution - Make a js file for this code and run in shell command using  `node your-file.js`