# How to execute mongodb commands from bash shell?

Tags: mongodb, command, command-line-interface, execute

I searched and found that one can use `--eval` but this does not work from CLI as you were inside mongodb shell.

For example I can not `show databases` with `--eval`

```
mongo -u root -p pass --eval "show dbs"

MongoDB shell version v4.2.18
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("80746969-2c86-45dc-603f-7f98882e578c") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.18
2022-03-10T15:33:22.711+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell eval):1:5
2022-03-10T15:33:22.711+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code -4
```

I was hoping there is something like mysql's `mysql -e "show databases"`

Answer (score 5):

`show databases` is a special command. Instead you can use `listDatabases` admin command:

```
mongo "mongodb://root:pass@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin" --norc --quiet --eval "db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases"
```

Comment: Thanx, the `show databases` was an example of how I want to be executing commands from the terminal without being inside the mongo shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

```
 echo 'db.testCollection.findOne({ "_id": "xxx" })' |  mongo --port 27017 testDatabase --authenticationDatabase=admin -u myUser -p  <myPassWord>  > output.txt
```

But there is many other ways to do it , check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts) there is multiple options already described ...

Comment: This has a lot of irrelevant info but it gave me the general idea which is `echo "<cmd>" | mongo` . 
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a valid workaround:

```
  echo "show dbs" | mongo -u root -p pass
```

Returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.18
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.18
admin              0.000GB
config             0.000GB
local              0.025GB
bye
```

Comment: Hello DimiDak

can we use same for setting parameters like this 
echo "db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4"})" | mongo dbname